# SugarCRM: Calculating Ratios?

Tags: sugarcrm

SugarCRM Pro 6.5.8

In our Calls module we have an option for users to select what the results were for a particular logged call.  This is done by selecting a value from a dropdown such as "Set Appointment."

I would like to create a report of some type that will display a ratio of the total number of an individual user's logged calls for the month versus how many appointments were set based on the "Set Appointment" option in a dropdown.  Essentially, how many calls did certain users need to make in order to set X number of appointments for the month.

Is this something that can be done out-of-the-box with SugarCRM Pro 6.5.8?  I was thinking of trying to use calculated fields, but I am unsure how exactly to build that with the formula builder, as I would need the report to calculate the ratio for each user out of a list of certain users.

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your requirement correctly, you can do something like following,

```
Create Matrix report
Filter : Date Start :: This month
Group by : Assigned User (username) & Status (Or the field which has "Set Appointment")
Display summary : Calls(Assigned to User), Calls(Status), Calls(SUM: Duration hours) ,  Calls(SUM: Duration minutes)
Chart option : Vertical bar and Data series (Duration hours/minutes your choice)
```

Let me know if thats what you were looking for!